# How to translate Postgresql 9.3 query for use on Postgresql 8.4?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, postgresql-8.4

On development, I have a Postgresql 9.3.10 database, and the following query works perfectly:

```
@playlist_ids = @playlist.user_ids
@more_playlists = Playlist.joins(:users).where.not('playlists.id = ? OR playlists.id = ?', 30, 41).where(users: {id: @playlist_ids}).group('playlists.id').order('count(*) desc')
```

In a nutshell, for a Playlist `@playlist`, this query lists all the other Playlists that share a User with `@playlist`, ordered by how many they share.

However, on production I'm using a Postgresql 8.4.22 database, so that same query returns this error:

```
PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "playlists.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT "playlists".* FROM "playlists" INNER JOIN "playlist...
           ^
: SELECT "playlists".* FROM "playlists" INNER JOIN "playlist_users" ON "playlist_users"."playlist_id" = "playlists"."id" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "playlist_users"."user_id" WHERE (NOT (playlists.id = 30 OR playlists.id = 41)) AND "users"."id" IN (45, 89, 71, 117, 115, 173, 177, 180, 161, 220, 223, 199, 221, 239, 204, 205, 206, 207, 211, 261, 282, 284, 286, 251, 252, 255, 310, 311, 315, 318, 307, 362, 319, 306, 289, 316, 305, 321, 322, 330, 333, 292, 294, 304, 300, 340, 341, 342, 343, 405, 406, 410, 408, 409, 407, 413, 416, 417, 418, 425, 427, 392, 401, 403, 445, 446, 449, 450, 379, 456, 451, 454, 459, 437, 442, 444, 496, 501, 518, 548, 549, 533, 553, 1112, 1113, 1459, 455, 348, 1458, 242, 1275, 151, 1890, 336, 203, 404, 166, 453, 114, 157, 285, 448, 447, 443, 550, 2167, 2168, 287, 320, 293, 65, 2098, 2097, 2099, 387, 3, 2175, 2170, 2174, 2182, 2171, 438, 2180, 2181, 2169, 2176, 347, 2429, 2177, 2445, 2178, 2447, 58, 2480, 390, 452, 554, 555, 313, 92, 275, 335, 428, 167, 302, 2173, 1538) GROUP BY playlists.id  ORDER BY count(*) desc
```

How can I alter my query to work with Postgresql 8.4?

---

**Associations**

```
class Playlist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :playlist_users
  has_many :users, :through => :playlist_users
end

class PlaylistUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :playlist
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :playlist_users
  has_many :playlists, :through => :playlist_users
end
```

Comment: "playlists.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

There's your answer right there.

Comment: @diego.greyrobot How can I write a query that would accomplish that?

Comment: Just add that field to the group method

Comment: You have to add all fields you want to select to the `group` method. Or, y'know, use a recent version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't talk about rail but I dont know why this work in 9.3, because shouldn't work neither.

I suggest you try this query direct on your database. (9.3 and 8.4)

Your sql have this

```
SELECT "playlists".* // <- multiple fields 
FROM "playlists"
INNER JOIN "playlist_users" ON "playlist_users"."playlist_id" = "playlists"."id"
INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "playlist_users"."user_id"
WHERE (
        NOT (
            playlists.id = 30
            OR playlists.id = 41
            )
        )
    AND "users"."id" IN (45, 89, 71, 117, 115, 173, 177, 180, 161, 220, 223, 199, 221, 239, 204, 205, 206, 207, 211, 261, 282, 284, 286, 251, 252, 255, 310, 311, 315, 318, 307, 362, 319, 306, 289, 316, 305, 321, 322, 330, 333, 292, 294, 304, 300, 340, 341, 342, 343, 405, 406, 410, 408, 409, 407, 413, 416, 417, 418, 425, 427, 392, 401, 403, 445, 446, 449, 450, 379, 456, 451, 454, 459, 437, 442, 444, 496, 501, 518, 548, 549, 533, 553, 1112, 1113, 1459, 455, 348, 1458, 242, 1275, 151, 1890, 336, 203, 404, 166, 453, 114, 157, 285, 448, 447, 443, 550, 2167, 2168, 287, 320, 293, 65, 2098, 2097, 2099, 387, 3, 2175, 2170, 2174, 2182, 2171, 438, 2180, 2181, 2169, 2176, 347, 2429, 2177, 2445, 2178, 2447, 58, 2480, 390, 452, 554, 555, 313, 92, 275, 335, 428, 167, 302, 2173, 1538)
GROUP BY playlists.id  // <- a single field agregation'
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

`GROUP BY` fields should match `SELECT` fields. Only mySQL support that crazy things.

Your query should be something like

```
SELECT playlists.id, playlists.name, COUNT(*)
FROM ....
GROUP BY playlists.id, playlists.name
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```